# What does it mean if both LEDs are lit up?

Tags: boot, power, boot-issues, pi-2

I recently got a RPi and when I plug it in both LEDs light up solid without flickering. It also does not show up on the monitor. Everywhere I've looked it says they should be flashing but they aren't. How do i fix this?  It's a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1

Comment: Which model of Pi?

Comment: Rasoberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1

Comment: Red power LED should be solid.  Green LED solid - never heard of that, sounds like a problem with the SD card.

Comment: But what could've caused the problem/ how could i fix it. I've been googling for a while and can't find anything

Comment: All I can suggest is that you re-image the SD card.  Has this Pi ever booted?

Comment: Whoever marked this as "an exact duplicate", certainly didn't really bother reading the questions. That other "exact" duplicate question is clearly about the SD card specifically. And this one is clearly about the LEDs, i.e. when are both lit (the card is not even on the radar here). Despite the title. Which is, indeed, (roughly, not "exactly", BTW) the same. In fact, that other question is grossly mistitled, so *that* should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue and the problem ended up being my SD card. I also had no display and the similar red and green light issue.

To rectify, I configured my SD card to Raspbian using Win32DiskImager and it worked. I was using the same Pi as you too.