# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B 1GB not booting - RED and GREEN leds always on - SDCARD working on Pi 1B+

Tags: pi-2, boot, sd-card, raspbian-jessie

I am using my raspberry pi 2 model B as a server run jessie. Suddenly, it cannot boot and the RED and GREEN leds on without blinking. I took the sdcard and opened it in laptop, I could navigate through the sdcard. "scan for fix" said the sd card was okay.

I put the sd card on my raspberry pi 1 B+. it works flawlessly. Whats wrong with my pi 2? Can anyone help to make it run again?

TIA

Daniel

Comment: Is your power supply sufficient(above 2 amps) to power the Pi?

Comment: Should be enough since it used to be working and the same power supply can power my other raspberry pi B+.

Comment: The Pi two draws more power as it has more CPU cores, but what is more likely is that there is a problem with the Pi, I'd recommend that you try a different sd card and see if that works for you

Comment: Yes, I am afraid problem with my pi 2 since the same sd card were reimaged and still both led on but not blinking. I need to buy new sdcard first before I can try again with another sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

A lack of blinking of the green LED frequently indicates an issue with the SD card or the OS (see [this troubleshooting page for more details](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_on.2C_green_LED_does_not_flash.2C_nothing_on_display)).  Since it is working for you on another Pi, the SD card seems fine, but you may have a version of firmware that is not supported.  When I got my Pi 2, I was unable to boot it with the SD card from my Pi 1.

[This SO page with a related issue may also be useful to you](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/51847/38271).

Comment: The funny thing is that it used to be working fine for almost a year. Suddenly, it stopped working last week. But, the same sd card run fine on pi B+.

Comment: Note the solid green led (no blinking) does not indicate an issue with the OS.  It indicates an issue with the card or card reader -- it has not even gotten to the point where it has attempted to load an OS.  Exactly the same thing will happen with *no* SD card inserted (which is not "an issue with the OS").